# Prop sharing between components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I know, this topic has been handeled a lot, but I am still lost in my particular example. I have a react-select component, which is a part of another component, which is a part of App component.

**SubjectSelect.tsx**

```
export default function SubjectSelect({handleChange, value}) {
  
  return (
    <>
      <Select
          placeholder="Choose subject"
          value={value} // set selected value
          onChange={handleChange} // assign onChange function
      />
      <div><b>Your choice: </b> {value} </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**FormStepOne.tsx**

```
import SubjectSelect from "../components/SubjectSelect";

export const SubjectSelector = ({value, handleChange}) => {
    
    return (
        <>
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
            Hi there! Please select book subject
        </h1>
            <SubjectSelect value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>
        </>
    );
}
```

And **App.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import  { SubjectSelector } from '../formSteps/stepOne'
import  { ShowcaseBooks } from '../formSteps/stepTwo'

const options = [
  { value: 'fiction', label: 'Fiction' },
  { value: 'science', label: 'Science' },
]

export default function App() {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState('')
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
  const handleChange = e => {
    setSelectedValue(e.value);
    alert('huhu')
  }
  const value = options.find(obj => obj.value === selectedValue)
  return (
    <div className="bg-blue-200">
      <div className="container mx-auto py-36 bg-blue-200">
        <div className="mt-12 px-96">
          <SubjectSelector 
            options={options}
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}/>
          <ShowcaseBooks books={books}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Somehow I am not passing the props right, so that my components showcase several errors. App.tsx complains about options and onChange, but I am lost and don't reallyfully undertand what is wrong and how to pass props corretly, so my App.js and therefore Showcase books "know" the selectdValue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you pass the `handleChange` function to `SubjectSelector` on the `onChange` prop, while that component is expecting it on a prop named `handleChange`.

In App.tsx you need something like this

```
  <SubjectSelector 
    options={options}
    value={value}
    handleChange={handleChange}/> // This is the fix
```

Because when you do this

```
export const SubjectSelector = ({value, handleChange}) =>
```

You're telling the component the name of the props to expect. You need to change your Subject selector in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But now setting the value is somehow broken ... const subject = options.find(obj => obj.value === selectedValue) and then using it in an component value={subject} throws an error. Maybe you know, what is happening there?

Answer (score 0):

For first loading, the prop `value` you send is empty (because change event is not triggered). so It will turn your app into error.

So you need to check it not `empty` before parse it to HTML

SubjectSelect.tsx

```
export default function SubjectSelect({ options, handleChange, selectedVal }) {
  return (
    <>
      <select
        value={selectedVal && selectedVal.value} // set selected value
        onChange={handleChange} // assign onChange function
      >
        <option>Choose subject</option>
        {options.map((item: any) => {
          return (
            <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
              {item.label}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
      <div>
        <b>Your choice: </b> {selectedVal && selectedVal.value}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

FormStepOne.tsx

```
import SubjectSelect from "./SubjectSelect";

const SubjectSelector = ({ selectedVal, handleChange, options }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
        Hi there! Please select book subject
      </h1>
      <SubjectSelect
        options={options}
        selectedVal={selectedVal}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default SubjectSelector;
```

And do not use `value` as `variable` name or `prop` to avoid conflict with `key` of object.
Getting value from change event should be `e.target.value`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SubjectSelector from "./SubjectSelect";

const options = [
  { value: "fiction", label: "Fiction" },
  { value: "science", label: "Science" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value);
    alert(e.target.value);
  };
  const selectVal = options.filter((obj) => obj.value === selectedValue)[0];

  return (
    <div className="bg-blue-200">
      <div className="container mx-auto py-36 bg-blue-200">
        <div className="mt-12 px-96">
          <SubjectSelector
            options={options}
            selectedVal={selectVal}
            handleChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check my complete answer here. I hope it might helps you

https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-smoke-n0eyjc?file=/src/App.tsx:0-804

Comment: Why selectVal && selectedVal.value. It works just with this: selectedVal={selectedValue}, and then just selectedVal in children

Comment: @KatharinaSchreiber selectVal is just variable name, selectedVal is prop name.